# How to interact with code cells in a Jupyter notebook via a REST API?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, remote-access, apache-zeppelin

What I'm trying to do is making a python or R interpreter server.

And I want to make this server able to interactive with my web application.

For example, Writing some code block, request execute these code block to interpreter server and get result of execution.

It seems [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/) offering that kind of feature via rest api

But [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Notebook-Server-API) seems not offering such features.

Is there any way to interactive with code cell in jupyter notebook via REST API??

Answer (score 2):

Use [jupyter kernel gateway](https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway).

Do this from the terminal on the machine where Jupyter is running.

```
pip install jupyter_kernel_gateway
jupyter kernelgateway
```

Then in a notebook, instrument a cell with something like this

```
# GET /hello/world
print("hello world")
```

Now if you visit the url of the notebook with `/hello/world` appended (so it will be something like `http://host:port/hello/world`) you should get back `hello world`.

There's a lot more including support for `R`.

Of course, details will differ for you so read the manual